# Can azure event hub ingest json events from azure blog storage without writing any code?

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

Is it possible to use some ready made construct in azure cloud environment to ingest the events (in json format) that are currently stored in azure blob storage and have it submit those events directly to azure event hub without writing any (however small) custom code? In other words, I would like to use configuration driven approach only.

Comment: And what would be the destination, what will process the messages in the hub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. You can try to use Azure Logic Apps to realize your needs without any code or just with some function expressions, please refer to the offical documents of [Azure Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/) to know more details.

The logic flow is as the figure below.

[image]

You can refer to my sample below to make it works.
[image]

---

Here is my sample to receive an event from my EventHub and transfer to Azure Blob Storage to create a new blob for storing the event data.

1. Create an Azure Logic App instance on Azure portal, it should be easy for you.
2. Move to the tab `Logic app designer` to configure the logic flow.
   [image]
3. Click `Save` and `Run` buttons. Then, use `ServiceBusExplorer` (downloaded from https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer/releases) to send event message and check whether new blob created using [`AzureStorageExplorer`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/). It works fine after a few minutes.

   [image]

   [image]

   [image]

Comment: The OP needs it the other way around. So blob storage would be the trigger and event hub would be the destination. Out of curiosity, is that doable as well as afaik you can only act on the event hub, not send messages to it using logic apps.

Comment: @PeterBons Oh, yes. My fault. I have update my post to add an image for explaination.

Comment: Peter Pan: What if I can not use the logic app, is there any other way?

Comment: @Raghu Without writing any code, Azure Logic Apps is the only one choice. Otherwise, you can try Azure Functions with Blob Trigger.